# Save search patterns with SublimeText

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Often we write regex patterns in SublimeText with the "Search" or "Replace" feature:

[image]

and then a few weeks later we need it again, but the only option to find it again is to use the <kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>DOWN</kbd> key to browse the past Regex history.

These patterns don't have any name, and it's difficult to re-find them.

**Question: is there a way to display favorite regex patterns in a handy way in SublimeText?**

Example: `(^\n)|(\s*#.*)` this allows to remove empty lines and lines with comments, I'd like to be able to have easy access to it in Sublime.

Comment: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/new?template=enhancement_or_feature_request.md